# Non aggregated average in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, average

Is there a way to calculate an average of results returned by a subquery without using aggregated functions?

Hypothetical example:

I want to select average maximum invoice in a month for each account. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT
   accounts.*,
   **AVERAGE**(SELECT MAX(`amount`)
               FROM invoices
               WHERE invoices.account_id = accounts.id
               GROUP BY invoices.month) as `average_max`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Average is by definition an aggregating function, as it needs to operate on an aggregate of data.

To get what you want I would do:

```
SELECT
  accounts.*, avg_amount.amount AS avg_amount
FROM
  accounts
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT account_id, AVG(amount) AS amount FROM (
    SELECT month, account_id, MAX(amount) AS amount FROM invoices GROUP BY month, account_id
  ) AS max_amount USING(account_id)
) AS avg_amount ON (accounts.id = avg_amount.account_ID)
```